# Rails attribute missing match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am developing a rails application similar to blogging site. There are four attributes in my model: `header`, `notice`, `tag`, `post_date` (the day of the event).

When I try to find the posts in my rails console with date as today, it returns the posts with `post_date` as today.

```
Post.find_by(post_date: Time.new.to_date.to_s)
```

But when I try to implement it in `static_pages_controller`, it shows the following error:

```
match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
```

Here is my definition of controller in `static_pages_controller`:

```
def about
  @post = Post.find_by(post_date: Time.new.to_date.to_s)
end
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Here is my static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def help
        @search = Post.search do 
            fulltext params[:search]
        end
        @post = @search.results
    end
    def home
    if params[:tag]
        @post = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
        @post = Post.all
    end
  end

  def about
    @post = Post.find_by(post_date: Time.new.to_date.to_s)
  end
end
```

and below is my about.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = "container">

                <% @post.reverse.each do |t| %>

                <div class = "col-md-10 blogShort">
                <div class= "post-home">
                <h3><%= t.header %></h3>
                <hr>
                <article>
                    <p>
                        <%= t.notice %>
                    </p>
                </article>

                <hr>
                <p>Tags: <%= raw t.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></p>


                                </div>
                                </div>
                <% end %>



    <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Post your controller

Comment: What you claim to be an error (message?) is not an error.

Comment: Please post the entire error message you receive, along with any stack trace.

Comment: NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#about
undefined method `reverse' for #<Post:0x007f2e213d44f0>
                
      else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for this is that in the `#home` and `#help` methods, `@post` represents a collection of posts.

In `#about`, because you're using `find_by`, rails returns a single instance of `Post`.  This is problematic when you try to use `@post.reverse`, because `@post` is a single object and does not respond to methods such as `reverse` and `each`.

Instead of using `@post.reverse.each` in the view, remove this portion and instead use `@post` in place of `t`.

Comment: I don't think so. My sqlite database contains more than 1 posts with date as today and it should return collection of posts. If this is not the right way to that, then show me any method via which I can do that.

Comment: Use `Post.where` instead of `Post.find_by` if you want to receive more than 1 result.

Comment: Thank you, It works. Where should I use "where" and where "find_by" if you could make it clear it to me, that would be helpful.

Comment: Any time you want to display multiple results (such as an index page), use `where`.  If you want to display only a single object (show/edit/update pages), use `find` or `find_by`.